# Can I define width for a Flutter widget in percentage instead of pixels?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Ideally, I'd like to do this

```
SizedBox(
    height: 20.0,
    width: 25%,
),
```

instead of

```
SizedBox(
    height: 20.0,
    width: 150.0,
),
```

Thanks! Super new to Flutter, appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25;
```

It gets the width of the device and multiplies it by 0.25 for that 25% you are looking for. Hope it helps!